# What are the realistic limits of human drug enhancement?

Tags: internal-consistency, biochemistry, medicine

Assuming fairly plausible technologies, what is the most fairly simple drugs could do?

In The Expanse there is a focus drug used by a Martian interrogator that allows him to be better at reading people. Is this a realistic drug?

The second and cooler example is the use of an adrenaline amplifier that gives limited bursts of superhuman strength, with the cost that it knocks out the user after use. Is this a realistic drug?

There is also the film and TV series Limitless which has a drug that massively increases memory, intelligence, and social skills. Is this a realistic drug?

How plausible is this pathway, and how should we tell if other drugs are likely to be possible to create with near future technology?

How would it work as a pill vs an injection?

Comment: Questions should not be open ended. "what other sort of things could be done?" is open ended.

Comment: There's a lot of research on the subject already. For example a drug supposed to keep soldiers awake for longer was tested and its still on the market today: crystal meth. Ofcourse its not used by the military anymore (legally).

Comment: I would close this question as "how plausible" show lack of research in this topic.

Comment: Researching whats in the High level bodybuilders daily cocktail of injections and tablets gives you a good idea on people pushing things to the limits, from steroid and testosterone injections to ephedrine and the latest ADHD tablets.

Answer (score 2):

The big problem with augmentation is that evolution is pretty good at it. It's had billions of years to optimize the body, and it's not easily upgraded as a general matter. That said, there are several exceptions.

1. Evolutionary restrictions, or things beyond biology. Biology can optimize, but there are limits to what you can do with cells and growing things part by part. Metal swords can be harder and sharper and more deadly than any biological weapon because they use heat beyond. This works well for simple properties like hardness or such, but works less well for complicated abilities, and is limited by our science. Antibiotics work because fungi and such can produce antibacterial chemicals beyond our human forms. Magical nanites or such could do all sorts of augmentation, like add in circuit boards or such, but most drugs will be more limited.
2. Different values. A lot of drugs work like this. Evolutionarily, our bodies have had priorities, and in modern life we have different priorities. Evolutionarily, we were optimized for sleeping at night. We use caffeine now and blue light to artificially work longer hours. Stimulants work in a similar way- normally we only activate our muscle's full strength in dire situations, but they can force that on demand. Contraceptives work the same way, stopping you from having kids even if your body wants them. Alcohol removes social inhibitions, for people with psychological issues.
3. Changed supply issues. Evolutionarily, we didn't have access to infinite resources. Malnutrition and disease can reduce our body's strength. By altering these things we can improve our body's function, though only to a limit.

Now, let's look at all of the examples.

1. Improving your ability to read people. This is a #1 issue. Our brains have evolved massively to improve social skills. It's gonna be very hard to improve this. Genetic improvements or computer databases tied into the nervous system would be needed. We aren't likely to have any drug like this for a long time.
2. An adrenaline amplifier is totally plausible. The body is already designed to go into overdrive with adrenaline. By adding in extra resources (#3) and maximizing our adrenal response (#2) you can substantially boost human strength. For major improvements, you'll need #1. Many other ape species have greater strength than humans say, because their muscles contain more fast twitch muscle fibers, which have reduced endurance and but greater strength.
3. Intelligence is already fairly optimized in the brain, since it offers a massive evolutionary advantage. We know in real life that there aren't many effective nootropics which enhance intelligence, and they generally come with major side effects. The limitless drug is fairly implausible for our current stage of development. We are not likely to have this for a very long time.

Pill vs injection is gonna change the intensity of the dose. Injected drugs go directly into the bloodstream and act faster. If you want super adrenaline, easier to inject it, easier to make it act on the brain. But, pills are easier to take.

So, when making fictional drugs, generally look at those three things to see if it's plausible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Nepene Nep is hard to argue with. But it is limited to drug-based enhancements.

I would only add that focused training can also produce some of these results in the here-and-now and without some of the nasty side effects. For example, agents in protective services are trained to spot micro expressions that give away the individual's intent. Skilled interrogators have comparable skills.

I am not anti-drug. I only argue that there are other, equally useful, ways to reach the desired capabilities.

Comment: Yeah, you can train people to be better socially or to do improved feats, but they were asking about drugs, so I limited it to drugs.

Comment: As you should have. I was being (and still am) contrarian. My "answer" was directed at the original question. Quick fixes (i.e., drugs) are not necessarily superior to long term solutions (i.e., training and and discipline), in spite of the current fondness for instant gratification.